# Counting the number of passes through a CSV file in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

Am I missing an easy way to do this?

I have a CSV file with a number of params in it, and in my test I want to be able to make some of the fields unique across CSV repetitions with a suffix determined by the number of times I've looped through the file.

So suppose my CSV (simplified) had:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

I want to generate in the test

```
abc_1
def_1
ghi_1    <hit EOF>
abc_2
def_2
ghi_2    <hit EOF>
abc_3
def_3
ghi_3
```

I thought I could set up a counter to run parallel to my CSV loop, but that won't work unless I increment it by 1/n each iteration, where n is the number of lines in my CSV file. Which you can't do because counters are integers.

I'm going to go flail around and see if I can come up with a solution, but in case I'm not successful, has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've used an EOF marker row (index column with something like "EOF" or "END", etc) and used an IF controller with either a non-resetting counter OR user-variables incremented via javascript in a BSF element (BSF assertion or whatever, just a mechanism to run the script).

Unfortunately its the best solution I've come up with without putting too much effort into it.